# Training roberta model on imdb movie reviews dataset giving this error?

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model

```py
def convert_data_to_examples(train, test, review, sentiment): 
    train_InputExamples = train.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[review], 
                                                          label = x[sentiment]), axis = 1)

    validation_InputExamples = test.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[review], 
                                                          label = x[sentiment]), axis = 1,)

  
    return train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples

train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train,  test, 'review',  'sentiment')
```

**NameError: name 'InputExample' is not defined**

After running this part of code its gives error. Please tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: Please always include the whole error stacktrace and not just the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from transformers import InputExample
```